# Symfony2 - Custom twig extension not being recognized

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've followed the [Symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) on the subject, but my twig extension is not being seen/recognized by twig.

My extension class:

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Twig;

class RoundExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(new \Twig_SimpleFilter('round', array($this, 'roundFilter')));
    }

    public function roundFilter($number, $factor = 4)
    {
        $round = (ceil($number * $factor)) / $factor;

        return number_format($round, 2);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'round_extension';
    }
}
```

And my services.yml:

```
services:
    acme.twig.round_extension:
        class: Acme\MyBundle\Twig\RoundExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Finally, the error:

> The filter "round" does not exist in MyBundle:Survey:results.html.twig at line 38

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Twig_Filter_Method`, not `Twig_SimpleFilter`

Answer (score 1):

For those who found this question, please do not follow the accepted answer. `Twig_Filter_Method` is deprecated and will be removed in Twig 2.0. `Twig_SimpleFilter` has to be used instead. Probably author just had to update his Twig version.